# Use variable inside style tag Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to use a animation-delay dynamically inside a `ngFor` loop. So I am using `style="animation-delay:'i's;"` where i is the loop variable.
This is not working.
My code is like below:

```
<div class="yourdiv" *ngFor = "let item of gvp.userMessages;let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"
    style="animation-delay:'i's;">
                <div style="text-align:right;margin-right:10px">

                    <ion-icon  name="undo" class="rplymsg msgico"></ion-icon>
                    <ion-icon  name="trash" class="delmsg msgico" (click)="deleteMessage()"></ion-icon>

                </div>
                <div *ngFor = "let msg of item[1]" class="{{msg.substring(0,1) == 'R' ? 'receivedmsg left-top' : 'replymsg right-top' }}">
                {{msg.substring(2,msg.length)}}
                </div>               
    </div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here it is, this is how you should write it :

```
[ngStyle]="{'animation-delay.s': i}"
```

Here is the working example of it, please have a look :

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inline-style?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

---

> For more details please read :
>
> https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle
>
> ```
> [ngStyle]="{'max-width.px': widthExp}"
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Shorthand for most cases:

`[style.animation-delay.s]="i"`

or

`[style.max-width.%]="propertyOnController"`

for

```
@Component({...})
export class ControllerComponent {
    propertyOnController: number;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, that the accepted answer is out-dated. We should not use `NgStyle` anymore ([ref](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#style-binding)):

> The NgStyle directive can be used as an alternative to direct [style] bindings. However, using the above style binding syntax without NgStyle is preferred because due to improvements in style binding in Angular, **NgStyle no longer provides significant value, and might eventually be removed in the future**.

Instead use direct style-bindings as explained in [Ron Newcombs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51229136/1041641)